# How to set timezone before saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a Rails 3.2 web app and when I supply a date (as a string) to the object I saving the date that gets saved is one day before.

So if I supply 2014-06-18 the date that gets saved is 2014-06-17.
This is extremely annoying. Updated_at are saved correctly.

This is my code:

```
report = Timereport.new
report.status = "stop"
report.hours = 0
report.created_at = params[:created_at]
report.save
```

How can I fix this?

**Update**

```
params[:created_at] 
=> 2014-06-18

Time.zone
 => #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x007fd94fbcb170 @name="UTC", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Etc/UTC>, @current_period=nil>

'2014-06-18'.to_datetime
 => Wed, 18 Jun 2014 00:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: What is your local time zone?

Comment: Assuming your `time_zone` is `Eastern Time (US & Canada)` you can set `config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'` in your `application.rb` to read the dates as per your local time zone.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not changing this. Rails saves all dates as UTC in your database so they can be localized later.

What you want to do instead is have ActiveRecord translate the dates to a time zone when reading them from the database.

You can do this globally in `config/application.rb` with the `config.time_zone` setting.

```
# Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
# Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
# config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

You can also do this according to the user's time zone, but it sounds like you just want to take care of it globally.

Answer (score 0):

What is in

```
params[:created_at]
```

What shows you

```
'2014-06-18'.to_datetime
```

in the console?

And sure, what is

```
Time.zone
```

this will helps you/us to see more.

Comment: Any ideas what I can do based of off this new information?

Comment: OK, it depends on the difference between the rails-app Time.zone, and the Time.zone of your computer. Look, which Time.zone has your Computer. Set the Time.zone of the rails-app as mentioned from the Chris to the Time.zone of you computer and it will work. Or for quick test, you can set the Time.zone of you computer to the Etc/UTC and should work.